# How can I build an empty table to eventually hold a timestamp column and two float columns, strictly using numpy and no pandas allowed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, time-series, numpy-ndarray

I am a beginner at numpy.  I can't figure out (through online tutorials) how to make a table with 3 columns, the first a timestmap, and the other two of type float, of any given length `nrows`.

All examples seem to use pandas.  I tried a `pd.read_csv()` call of data in the right format and viewing its attributes with my debugger, but it has no dtype attribute, but instead `dtypes` and it's a length-7 tuple of floats and ints with no datetime, 7 being unrelated to the data I'm passing in.

Attempt:

```
import numpy as np

# Desired result:
# Type: datetime64, float, float
#       (a date)  ,  0.1,  0.2
#       (a date)  ,  0.3,  0.4
#        ...
#       nrows in length

nrows = 64
table = np.empty(shape=(nrows, 3), dtype=('datetime64', float, float))

print(table.dtype)
```

Gives:

```
line 11, in <module>
  table = np.empty(shape=(nrows, 3), dtype=('datetime64', float, float))

builtins.TypeError: Tuple must have size 2, but has size 3
```

So, I'm not sure how shape and dtype are supposed to relate to one another.

I'm pretty sure I have shape correct, so what is the proper usage of dtype in this use case?

I don't want to use pandas here because it runs very slow on my machine and I'm enjoying the speed of numpy with it's C implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
table = np.empty(shape=(nrows, 3), dtype=('datetime64,float,float'))
```

Comment: I don't think he wants 3 columns; just 3 fields.  And the `()` are unnecessary around the string.

Comment: @hpaulj what's the difference between a column and a field here?  I would ike the one  version that runs the fastest when doing many computations on the data.

Comment: A (n,3) array has to have the same dtype for all elements.  You could have one array with the time dtype and shape (n,) and another with (n,2) float.   As for speed, I can't say without knowledge of your calculations.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you!  So column here refers to matrix column and not "database column", while field here refers to your regular database "field/column".  Makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a `structured array`.  There's a whole doc page on that.  Getting `dtype` spec right takes some reading.  One format:

```
In [231]: table = np.zeros(shape=(4,), dtype='datetime64[ns],f,f')
In [232]: table
Out[232]: 
array([('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', 0., 0.),
       ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', 0., 0.),
       ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', 0., 0.),
       ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', 0., 0.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<M8[ns]'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

This is a (4,) shape, with 3 fields.  Not a (4,3).  Data for such an array is supplied field by field, or as a tuple for one element, or list of tuples.  That is, the input data needs to have the same sort of layout as the above display.

The pandas equivalent:

```
In [234]: import pandas as pd
In [235]: df = pd.DataFrame(table)
In [236]: df
Out[236]: 
          f0   f1   f2
0 1970-01-01  0.0  0.0
1 1970-01-01  0.0  0.0
2 1970-01-01  0.0  0.0
3 1970-01-01  0.0  0.0
In [238]: df.dtypes
Out[238]: 
f0    datetime64[ns]
f1           float32
f2           float32
```

and back to array:

```
In [239]: df.to_records(index=False)
Out[239]: 
rec.array([('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', 0., 0.),
           ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', 0., 0.),
           ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', 0., 0.),
           ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', 0., 0.)],
          dtype=[('f0', '<M8[ns]'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

`np.genfromtxt` with `dtypes=None` can load a csv file in much the same way as `pd.read_csv` (though the pandas read is usually faster).

Comment: Will this not work if I would like to address each "field" as a column like so:
`(table['Timestamp'] < some_datetime) & (table['data1'] > 2.0)` ?

Comment: Yes, you can do those sort of tests.  Read the `structured arrays` docs.  Fields are indexed by name, and as such end up behaving like an array of the same shape and dtype.  In structured arrays, fields are a lot like pandas columns (though the underlying data storage is different).